# What control could I use to show text in multiple columns?

Tags: microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, modern-ui

I'm wondering what is the multicolumn text control used in "News App", in Windows 8:

[image]

I have seen [this microsoft example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-text-display-sample-2593ba0a/) where they use fixed RichTextBlock and RichTextBlockOverflow inside a grid. There must be a better way to  do this (I hope). Do you know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's the best way to do it, if you are creating your app in XAML. However, if you are creating creating your app using HTML5/JavaScript you can achieve this using CSS Overflow Properties.

There is a video from the BUILD conference 2012, showing how this is done:
[Key technologies for building great reading experiences](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-118)
 - the overflow part begins after around 20 minutes.

*Note: The video talks about the possibilities and limitations of both HTML5 and XAML, and shows how it's done.*